# layoutSubviews called twice on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I'm overriding layoutSubviews in my subclass of UITableViewCell. I noticed that layoutSubviews is called twice for each cell. On the second call, the content view frame height is 1 less than the height on the first call:

```
@implementation MyUITableViewCellCell

+ (NSString *)asString:(CGRect) rect {
     NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"[%f %f %f %f]",
                 rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height];
     [res autorelease];
     return res;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"Here I am %@ frame=%@ cvframe=%@,
      self.text, 
      [MyUITableViewCellCell asString:self.frame],
      [MyUITableViewCellCell asString:self.contentView.frame]);
}

@end
```

Here's how the controller creates the table cells:

```
- (NSString*)dataAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSString* data = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Row %d", index];
    return [data autorelease];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Alex";

    NSInteger index = [indexPath row];
    MyUITableViewCellCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyUITableViewCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = [self dataAtIndex:index];
    return cell;
}
```

Output:

```
Here I am Row 0 frame=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 30.000000] cvframe=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 30.000000]
Here I am Row 1 frame=[0.000000 30.000000 320.000000 30.000000] cvframe=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 30.000000]
Here I am Row 0 frame=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 30.000000] cvframe=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 29.000000]
Here I am Row 1 frame=[0.000000 30.000000 320.000000 30.000000] cvframe=[0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 29.000000]
```

Are 2 call per cell expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `UITableView` resizes the height of the cell by one pixel to make room for drawing dividing lines. Your `layoutSubviews` method is getting called again after `UITableView` sets the new frame for the cell.